# How to maintain incrementing values in a column after removing rows from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I work with a test system that outputs a large CSV matrix of values which I then process using the Pandas module in Python. The parameters that system uses when testing a given part are governed by a predetermined sequence. A simplified example is shown here:

[Raw data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OPRq.png)

However, not all of these steps are desired in the output data. In fact, the rows containing a 'Clock Frequency' value of '3.0MHz' are only included to act as buffer points to allow a climate chamber to reach the intended temperature. I do not wish to include data collected at these parameters in my results.

I found I was pretty easily able to remove these rows from my data frame by using the below code. Note that in this example I am working with a Pandas data frame called 'csvDF'.

```
tempBuffers = csvDF[csvDF['Clock Frequency']==3e6].index
csvDF.drop(tempBuffers, inplace=True)
```

This produces the following output:

[Data frame with buffer steps removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUiQV.png)

The issue with this is that now my 'Sequence Step' column is wrong. I want the data table to appear as if those buffer steps never existed. The sequence steps should be sequential for all non-buffer steps. The desired output is shown below:

[Data frame with buffer steps removed and corrected sequence step column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj6yH.png)

What code do I need to instantiate in order to achieve this?

Comment: please provide a textual sample of your data for others to test and provide a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
n = 3 # number of rows in step
csvDF.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
csvDF['Sequence step'] = pd.Series(range(len(csvDF)))
csvDF['Sequence step'] = csvDF['Sequence step'].apply(lambda x: int(x / n))
```